# How to make custom bash commands? (running python, perl, ruby files)

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to use certain tools that run on Python/Perl/Ruby. For example, `myProgram.py` is stored in ~/folder1/folder2/. I'd like to run it with input from bash like `>>> myProgram -h`.

So far, I've read about 2 ways to do something similar:

1. Make files in a bin directory:

```
# in /bin/
~/folder1/folder2/myProgram
# this works when the target is a bash program
```

2. Edit `~/.bashrc` for a permanent alias:

```
# in ~/.bashrc
alias myProgram='python ~/folder1/folder2/myProgram.py'
```

Unfortunately, the 1st way doesn't seem to work with non-bash files (as far as I've tried), and the 2nd option just returns an error like `myProgram: command not found`.

How should I make bash commands for quick access to my Python/Perl/Ruby tools with input with the commands?

Answer (score 3):

To run your scripts like that you need three things:

1. Script must be in directory which is listed in your `$PATH` variable. If you put scripts to `~/bin`, to execute them without specifying full path to file anytime you login, you need to extend path in your `.bashrc` by adding following line `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin`. To see which directories are already in your path you can just print it `echo $PATH`. To make any change in `.bashrc` file you need relogin (or rerun bash).
2. Script must have executable bit permission set. To do so execute command `chmod +x /path/to/script`
3. Script must tell which interpreter to use to run it. For that a special first line in script is used called shebang: `#!/path/to/interpreter`. For Python that will be `#!/usr/bin/python`. As different OSes might have binaries in different places it is recommended to use shebang in form `#!/usr/bin/env python` which will execute default Python interpreter no matter where it is.

UPDATE: Based on comments I'm updating this answer with symlinking. If you just want to make tools you already have installed easier accessible, you don't have to create scripts. You just need to find executable of that tool (or if it is script, make it executable if it already isn't) and then place symlink (see `man ln`) to it into directory in your
$PATH (or add directory with executable to your $PATH).

NOTE: Just making script executable (see 2.) and adding `alias` to your `.bashrc` will work too, but it's quite inconvenient to add new alias every time you create new script.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob. Can you give an example script?

Comment: I tried ```#!/usr/bin/python /opt/myProgram/program.py``` (all in 1 line) and it *sort of* works, except it sometimes returns the error ```error: unrecognized arguments: /home/myName/bin/myProgram``` (the bin file is saved as ```myProgram```) and doesn't return the expected output. Sometimes it kinda works though. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh, if you want to create e.g. script that prints "hello world", call it hello and execute it by just typing `hello` on your commandline you'd need to create a file called `/home/yourName/bin/hello`. This file will contain two lines:  line 1 will be ```#!/usr/bin/env python``` and line 2 ```print("hello world")```. Then execute `chmod +x /home/yourName/bin/hello`. Last make sure that `$PATH` contains `/home/yourName/bin` (as well as others). Then you can just type in `hello` and it will print "hello world".

Comment: I'm installing a lot of tools in ```/opt``` and want to have all my custom ```bin``` files (commands) in ```~/bin```. The tools are made my others, each with 1 ```.py```/```.rb```/```.pl``` file. I'd like to make something in ```~/bin``` that points to and runs those, rather than making extra files in the tools' folders. In your example, the whole script seems to be in the bin file, which isn't what I'd like.

Comment: Aha, then just symlink your tool to ~/bin `ln -s /opt/tools/mytool.py ~/bin/mytool`. File in /opt/tools must still be executable.